# Find and Match cell from excel column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet which is sorted for **Column 2**(colm2) as shown in attached example.

[image: Sample Data]

It has duplicate cell values. Each duplicate cell has associated data.
Now I want to find and match duplicate from column2 and merge data in following way,

[image: Output value]

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62698523/need-help-getting-multiple-values-in-single-cell-with-condition-to-be-satisfied

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a